# who was used as a model for the likeness of Marion Bosworth in Call of duty Black ops 2?

Tags: video-games, call-of-duty

[image: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/callofduty/images/a/a4/Bosworth_Haiti_BOII.png/revision/latest?cb=20121127080643]

I know that the character is voiced by Cira Larkin, but I do not think that they used her likeness

Comment: Is this even on topic here? Were there science fiction or fantasy elements in CoD Black Ops II?

Comment: @Laurel Parts of the game are set in 2025 and feature (at the time) futuristic weaponry.